# Time dependent relationship between Employee and his Manager

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an input data set, given as under, which contains relationship between an Employee and his Manager for the time period 01-JAN-2018 to 31-JAN-2018.

**INPUT DATA SET:**

```
**EMP_ID    MGR_ID    FRM_DT         TO_DT**
EMP1      MGR1      01-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
EMP2      MGR2      01-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
EMP3      MGR3      01-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
EMP4      MGR4      01-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
EMP5      MGR5      01-JAN-2018    10-JAN-2018
EMP5      MGR1      11-JAN-2018    15-JAN-2018
EMP5      MGR2      16-JAN-2018    20-JAN-2018
EMP5      MGR3      21-JAN-2018    25-JAN-2018
EMP5      MGR4      26-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
EMP6      MGR6      01-JAN-2018    15-JAN-2018
EMP6      MGR2      18-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018
```

For instance, EMP1, EMP2, EMP3 & EMP4 report to MGR1, MGR2, MGR3, MGR4 for the entire duration i.e. from 01-JAN-2018 to 31-JAN-2018.
But for EMP5 & EMP6 situation is different. 
EMP5 kept swinging from one manager to another for the entire period (from 01-JAN to 10-JAN reported to MGR5, from 11-JAN to 15-JAN reported to MGR1,from 16-JAN to 20-JAN reported to MGR2, from 21-JAN to 25-JAN reported to MGR3,from 26-JAN to 31-JAN reported to MGR4). 
Whereas, EMP6 reported two managers during the period, (from 01-JAN-2018 to 10-JAN-2018 reported to MGR6, from 18-JAN-2018 to 31-JAN-2018 reported to MGR2)

**REQUIRED RESULT SET:**
Now, I want to present information contained in the data set in the following way

```
**MGR_ID    FRM_DT         TO_DT          SUB_ORD_CNT    SUB_ORDINATES**
MGR1      01-JAN-2018    10-JAN-2018    1              EMP1
MGR1      11-JAN-2018    15-JAN-2018    2              EMP1,EMP5
MGR1      16-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018    1              EMP1
MGR2      01-JAN-2018    15-JAN-2018    1              EMP2
MGR2      16-JAN-2018    17-JAN-2018    2              EMP2,EMP5
MGR2      18-JAN-2018    20-JAN-2018    3              EMP2,EMP5,EMP6
MGR2      21-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018    2              EMP2,EMP6
MGR3      01-JAN-2018    20-JAN-2018    1              EMP3
MGR3      21-JAN-2018    25-JAN-2018    2              EMP3,EMP5
MGR3      26-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018    1              EMP3
MGR4      01-JAN-2018    25-JAN-2018    1              EMP4
MGR4      26-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018    2              EMP4,EMP5
MGR5      01-JAN-2018    10-JAN-2018    1              EMP5
```

That is, I want to report how many employees(along with their comma seperated EMPIDs) reported to manger during specific timeslice with in period 01-JAN-2018 to 31-JAN-2018. 
For instance, MGR2 oversee two employess(EMP2 & EMP5) during 16-JAN-2018    17-JAN-2018 & during 18-JAN-2018 to 20-JAN-2018 MGR2 oversee three employees(EMP2, EMP5 & EMP6)

I am wondering, how is this possible with SQL. I am using 11g version of ORACLE DB.
Any lead towards solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Code to produce required data set is given under:

```
create table emp_mgr_relation
(
 emp_id varchar2(30),
 mgr_id varchar2(30),
 frm_dt date,
 to_dt date
 );
 /
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP1','MGR1','01-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP2','MGR2','01-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP3','MGR3','01-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP4','MGR4','01-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP5','MGR5','01-JAN-2018','10-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP5','MGR1','11-JAN-2018','15-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP5','MGR2','16-JAN-2018','20-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP5','MGR3','21-JAN-2018','25-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP5','MGR4','26-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP6','MGR6','01-JAN-2018','15-JAN-2018');
 insert into emp_mgr_relation values('EMP6','MGR2','18-JAN-2018','31-JAN-2018');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out another approach to solve the problem. This approach does not generate rows at run time hence addresses the concern discussed in the comments of earlier solution.

```
select mgr_id,
       final_slice_from dt_frm,
       final_slice_to dt_to,
       regexp_count(emps, ',') + 1 sub_ord_cnt,
       emps sub_ordinates
  from (select mgr_id,
               final_slice_from,
               final_slice_to,
               (select listagg(emp_id, ',') within group(order by emp_id)
                  from emp_mgr_relation y
                 where y.mgr_id = r.mgr_id
                   and (final_slice_from between y.frm_dt and y.to_dt or
                       final_slice_to between y.frm_dt and y.to_dt)) emps
          from (select mgr_id,
                       slice_from + frm_dt_adj final_slice_from,
                       slice_to + to_dt_adj final_slice_to
                  from (select mgr_id,
                               slice_from,
                               slice_to,
                               frm_dt_flg,
                               to_dt_flg,
                               decode(nvl(frm_dt_flg, '#'), '#', 1, 0) frm_dt_adj,
                               decode(nvl(to_dt_flg, '#'), '#', -1, 0) to_dt_adj
                          from (select a.mgr_id,
                                       a.slice_from,
                                       a.slice_to,
                                       (select 'Y'
                                          from dual
                                         where exists
                                         (select 1
                                                  from emp_mgr_relation e
                                                 where a.mgr_id = e.mgr_id
                                                   and a.slice_from = e.frm_dt)) frm_dt_flg,
                                       (select 'Y'
                                          from dual
                                         where exists
                                         (select 1
                                                  from emp_mgr_relation d
                                                 where a.mgr_id = d.mgr_id
                                                   and a.slice_to = d.to_dt)) to_dt_flg
                                  from (
                                        --create time slice using lead function
                                        select mgr_id,
                                                dt slice_from,
                                                lead(dt, 1) over(partition by mgr_id order by dt) slice_to
                                          from (
                                                 --list all distinct dates manager wise 
                                                 select distinct mgr_id, frm_dt dt
                                                   from emp_mgr_relation
                                                 union
                                                 select distinct mgr_id, to_dt
                                                   from emp_mgr_relation)) a
                                 where slice_to is not null))) r)
```

Query Result:

```
MGR_ID  DT_FRM      DT_TO   SUB_ORD_CNT SUB_ORDINATES
MGR1    1/1/2018    1/10/2018   1       EMP1
MGR1    1/11/2018   1/15/2018   2       EMP1,EMP5
MGR1    1/16/2018   1/31/2018   1       EMP1
MGR2    1/1/2018    1/15/2018   1       EMP2
MGR2    1/16/2018   1/17/2018   2       EMP2,EMP5
MGR2    1/18/2018   1/20/2018   3       EMP2,EMP5,EMP6
MGR2    1/21/2018   1/31/2018   2       EMP2,EMP6
MGR3    1/1/2018    1/20/2018   1       EMP3
MGR3    1/21/2018   1/25/2018   2       EMP3,EMP5
MGR3    1/26/2018   1/31/2018   1       EMP3
MGR4    1/1/2018    1/25/2018   1       EMP4
MGR4    1/26/2018   1/31/2018   2       EMP4,EMP5
MGR5    1/1/2018    1/10/2018   1       EMP5
MGR6    1/1/2018    1/15/2018   1       EMP6
```

Answer (score 1):

As a fairly brute-force approach, you could use a hierarchical query or recursive CTE to expand all the original date ranges into one row per employee per day:

```
with rcte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt, to_dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt, to_dt
  from emp_mgr_relation
  union all
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt + 1, to_dt
  from rcte1
  where to_dt > dt
)
select emp_id, mgr_id, dt from rcte1 order by dt, emp_id, mgr_id;

EMP_ID                         MGR_ID                         DT        
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
EMP1                           MGR1                           2018-01-01
EMP2                           MGR2                           2018-01-01
EMP3                           MGR3                           2018-01-01
EMP4                           MGR4                           2018-01-01
EMP5                           MGR5                           2018-01-01
EMP6                           MGR6                           2018-01-01
EMP1                           MGR1                           2018-01-02
EMP2                           MGR2                           2018-01-02
...
EMP6                           MGR2                           2018-01-30
EMP1                           MGR1                           2018-01-31
EMP2                           MGR2                           2018-01-31
EMP3                           MGR3                           2018-01-31
EMP4                           MGR4                           2018-01-31
EMP5                           MGR4                           2018-01-31
EMP6                           MGR2                           2018-01-31

184 rows selected.
```

and then aggregate those by manager and date:

```
with rcte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt, to_dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt, to_dt
  from emp_mgr_relation
  union all
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt + 1, to_dt
  from rcte1
  where to_dt > dt
),
cte2 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, count(*), listagg (emp_id,  ',') within group (order by emp_id)
  from rcte1
  group by mgr_id, dt
)
select * from cte2 order by mgr_id, dt;

MGR_ID                         DT         SUB_ORD_CN SUBORDINATES                  
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
MGR1                           2018-01-01          1 EMP1                          
MGR1                           2018-01-02          1 EMP1                          
MGR1                           2018-01-03          1 EMP1                          
...
MGR1                           2018-01-10          1 EMP1                          
MGR1                           2018-01-11          2 EMP1,EMP5                     
MGR1                           2018-01-12          2 EMP1,EMP5                     
MGR1                           2018-01-13          2 EMP1,EMP5                     
...

149 rows selected.
```

and then apply [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html):

```
with rcte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt, to_dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt, to_dt
  from emp_mgr_relation
  union all
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt + 1, to_dt
  from rcte1
  where to_dt > dt
),
cte2 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, count(*), listagg (emp_id,  ',') within group (order by emp_id)    
  from rcte1
  group by mgr_id, dt
),
cte3 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates, bucket) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates,
    row_number() over (partition by mgr_id, sub_ord_cn, subordinates order by dt)
      - row_number() over (partition by mgr_id order by dt)
  from cte2
)
select * from cte3 order by mgr_id, dt;

MGR_ID                         DT         SUB_ORD_CN SUBORDINATES                       BUCKET
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
MGR1                           2018-01-01          1 EMP1                                    0
MGR1                           2018-01-02          1 EMP1                                    0
...
MGR1                           2018-01-10          1 EMP1                                    0
MGR1                           2018-01-11          2 EMP1,EMP5                             -10
...
MGR1                           2018-01-15          2 EMP1,EMP5                             -10
MGR1                           2018-01-16          1 EMP1                                   -5
...
MGR6                           2018-01-15          1 EMP6                                    0

149 rows selected.
```

and then aggregate those manager buckets:

```
with rcte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt, to_dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt, to_dt
  from emp_mgr_relation
  union all
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt + 1, to_dt
  from rcte1
  where to_dt > dt
),
cte2 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, count(*), listagg (emp_id,  ',') within group (order by emp_id)    
  from rcte1
  group by mgr_id, dt
),
cte3 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates, bucket) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates,
    row_number() over (partition by mgr_id, sub_ord_cn, subordinates order by dt)
      - row_number() over (partition by mgr_id order by dt)
  from cte2
)
select mgr_id, min(dt) as frm_dt, max(dt) as to_dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates
from cte3
group by mgr_id, bucket, sub_ord_cn, subordinates
order by mgr_id, frm_dt;
```

which gets:

```
MGR_ID                         FRM_DT     TO_DT      SUB_ORD_CN SUBORDINATES                  
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
MGR1                           2018-01-01 2018-01-10          1 EMP1                          
MGR1                           2018-01-11 2018-01-15          2 EMP1,EMP5                     
MGR1                           2018-01-16 2018-01-31          1 EMP1                          
MGR2                           2018-01-01 2018-01-15          1 EMP2                          
MGR2                           2018-01-16 2018-01-17          2 EMP2,EMP5                     
MGR2                           2018-01-18 2018-01-20          3 EMP2,EMP5,EMP6                
MGR2                           2018-01-21 2018-01-31          2 EMP2,EMP6                     
MGR3                           2018-01-01 2018-01-20          1 EMP3                          
MGR3                           2018-01-21 2018-01-25          2 EMP3,EMP5                     
MGR3                           2018-01-26 2018-01-31          1 EMP3                          
MGR4                           2018-01-01 2018-01-25          1 EMP4                          
MGR4                           2018-01-26 2018-01-31          2 EMP4,EMP5                     
MGR5                           2018-01-01 2018-01-10          1 EMP5                          
MGR6                           2018-01-01 2018-01-15          1 EMP6                          

14 rows selected.
```

If you are on a version that has bugs with the recursive CTE (11.2.0.2 seems to only return 11 rows, probably because of 11840579, which was fixed in 11.2.0.3), you could use a hierarchical query instead; something like:

```
with cte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt + level - 1
  from emp_mgr_relation
  connect by emp_id = prior emp_id
  and mgr_id = prior mgr_id
  and frm_dt = prior frm_dt
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
  and level <= to_dt - frm_dt + 1  --correction here
),
cte2 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, count(*), listagg (emp_id,  ',') within group (order by emp_id)
  from cte1
  group by mgr_id, dt
),
cte3 (mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates, bucket) as (
  select mgr_id, dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates,
    row_number() over (partition by mgr_id, sub_ord_cn, subordinates order by dt)
      - row_number() over (partition by mgr_id order by dt)
  from cte2
)
select mgr_id, min(dt) as frm_dt, max(dt) as to_dt, sub_ord_cn, subordinates
from cte3
group by mgr_id, bucket, sub_ord_cn, subordinates
order by mgr_id, frm_dt;
```

which gets the same result.

Comment: Given SQL 'with rcte1 (emp_id, mgr_id, dt, to_dt) as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, frm_dt, to_dt
  from emp_mgr_relation
  union all
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt + 1, to_dt
  from rcte1
  where to_dt > dt
)
select emp_id, mgr_id, dt from rcte1 order by dt, emp_id, mgr_id;' is not returning 184 rows. I think there is some flaw in row generation logic.

Comment: How many is it returning? Oh... which version and patch level of Oracle are you on? This might be broken before 11.2.0.4 maybe, I vaguely remember a bug in this area. I just chucked this on db<>fiddle and it only found 11 rows; so does SQL Fiddle. They are both on 11.2.0.2...

Comment: Moreover to this, this approach can work in this specific scenario. But, think of the one where there are thousands of childs (Employee in this case) and their association with the parent(Manager in this case) can be change at the minute level (as opposed to day level in the example). Using this approach would generate millions or billions of rows at run time, which I believe would be much computationally expensive. If you come up with any improved approach to handle that much quantum, please share. Thanks for you time & effort!

Comment: Responding to your query, I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Then yes, that's bug 11840579, fixed in 11.2.0.3. I added a hierarchical query version. How well either scales is another matter, yes. But that's the scenario you asked about. I suppose you could look at collections or temporary tables but they have their own pros and cons. There may be a trick that doesn't require expanding first but I can't see one at the moment...

Comment: Thanks Alex! one more thing to be asked. First row of your result set (MGR1                           2018-01-01 2018-01-31          1 EMP1) should be split into two rows (i.e. MGR1      01-JAN-2018    10-JAN-2018    1              EMP1
MGR1      16-JAN-2018    31-JAN-2018    1              EMP1). Please refer to rownumber 1 & 3 in my "Required Result Set" data.

Comment: @RehanAli - argh, sorry, I forgot about that part. Updated. I'm sure this can be simplified a bit but I don't have time to look at it further, maybe someone else will post a better solution.

Comment: Thank Alex! for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by flipping the view from employee date ranges to manager ranges. i.e. for each manager, get the periods when their reports changed.

Do this by first converting the employee from/to dates to a single column of dates:

```
with dates as (
  select * from emp_mgr_relation
  unpivot (
    dt for ( src ) in ( frm_dt, to_dt )
  )
)
  select * from dates
  order  by mgr_id, dt;

EMP_ID   MGR_ID   SRC      DT            
EMP1     MGR1     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR1     FRM_DT   11-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR1     TO_DT    15-JAN-2018   
EMP1     MGR1     TO_DT    31-JAN-2018   
EMP2     MGR2     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR2     FRM_DT   16-JAN-2018   
EMP6     MGR2     FRM_DT   18-JAN-2018
...
```

You now need to turn this into start/end ranges. You can do this using lead() to get the next date by manager:

```
with dates as (
  select * from emp_mgr_relation
  unpivot (
    dt for ( src ) in ( frm_dt, to_dt )
  )
), ranges as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt, dt st_dt, src, 
         lead ( dt ) over ( partition by mgr_id order by dt )  en_dt
  from   dates
)
  select * from ranges
  order  by mgr_id, dt;

EMP_ID   MGR_ID   DT            ST_DT         SRC      EN_DT         
EMP1     MGR1     01-JAN-2018   01-JAN-2018   FRM_DT   11-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR1     11-JAN-2018   11-JAN-2018   FRM_DT   15-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR1     15-JAN-2018   15-JAN-2018   TO_DT    31-JAN-2018   
EMP1     MGR1     31-JAN-2018   31-JAN-2018   TO_DT    <null>        
EMP2     MGR2     01-JAN-2018   01-JAN-2018   FRM_DT   16-JAN-2018   
EMP5     MGR2     16-JAN-2018   16-JAN-2018   FRM_DT   18-JAN-2018   
EMP6     MGR2     18-JAN-2018   18-JAN-2018   FRM_DT   20-JAN-2018 
...
```

Then join in the row for the employees that reported to the manager in the time period:

```
with dates as (
  select * from emp_mgr_relation
  unpivot (
    dt for ( src ) in ( frm_dt, to_dt )
  )
), ranges as (
  select emp_id, mgr_id, dt, dt st_dt, src, 
         lead ( dt ) over ( partition by mgr_id order by dt )  en_dt
  from   dates
)
  select e.mgr_id, src, 
         case 
           when src = 'TO_DT' then st_dt + 1
           else st_dt
         end st_dt,
         case
           when src = 'TO_DT' or 
                lead ( src ) over ( 
                  partition by e.mgr_id order by st_dt 
                ) = 'TO_DT' or
                en_dt =  max ( en_dt ) over ( 
                           partition by e.mgr_id 
                         ) 
           then en_dt
           else
             en_dt - 1
         end en_dt,
         count(*) sub_ord_cn, 
         listagg ( e.emp_id, ',' ) 
           within group ( order by e.emp_id ) subordinates
  from   ranges r
  join   emp_mgr_relation e
  on     r.mgr_id = e.mgr_id
  and    e.frm_dt <= st_dt
  and    e.to_dt >= en_dt
  and    st_dt < en_dt
  group  by e.mgr_id, st_dt, en_dt, src
  order  by e.mgr_id, st_dt, en_dt;

MGR_ID   SRC      ST_DT         EN_DT         SUB_ORD_CN   SUBORDINATES     
MGR1     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   10-JAN-2018              1 EMP1             
MGR1     FRM_DT   11-JAN-2018   15-JAN-2018              2 EMP1,EMP5        
MGR1     TO_DT    16-JAN-2018   31-JAN-2018              1 EMP1             
MGR2     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   15-JAN-2018              1 EMP2             
MGR2     FRM_DT   16-JAN-2018   17-JAN-2018              2 EMP2,EMP5        
MGR2     FRM_DT   18-JAN-2018   20-JAN-2018              3 EMP2,EMP5,EMP6   
MGR2     TO_DT    21-JAN-2018   31-JAN-2018              2 EMP2,EMP6        
MGR3     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   20-JAN-2018              1 EMP3             
MGR3     FRM_DT   21-JAN-2018   25-JAN-2018              2 EMP3,EMP5        
MGR3     TO_DT    26-JAN-2018   31-JAN-2018              1 EMP3             
MGR4     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   25-JAN-2018              1 EMP4             
MGR4     FRM_DT   26-JAN-2018   31-JAN-2018              2 EMP4,EMP5        
MGR5     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   10-JAN-2018              1 EMP5             
MGR6     FRM_DT   01-JAN-2018   15-JAN-2018              1 EMP6
```

Note there's a bit of date fudging because you're reporting the end date as the day before the start of the next.

While this joins back to emp_mgr_relation, you don't need to generate a row/employee/day.  Which in many cases will be the number of periods/manager you need in your output anyway.

So it's likely to process fewer rwos than the brute-force recursive method. And so be faster.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you are a guru :)